# I want a literal 'Read/view Only' library - no save, download or print functionality

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, security, read-only

I have a number of documents that I want to be literally 'Read Only' in a Library (ideally view in the browser). This means that I want to disable the 'Save As', download and print functionality to maintain security to the files.

I saw [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44703/how-to-disable-save-as-button-of-sharepoint-2010-document) but there is not an answer to disabling the 'Save As' functionality.

Any help would be welcomed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint does not provide this functionality. Even if you restrict save or download by using Javascript or any medium. users can still take print screens . (Talking from security perspective of your document)

Even with read/view access they can still download the document.

Right solution for your problem will be integration with IRM. This comes with windows server and needs AD access. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638140(v=exchg.150).aspx.

You can restrict print screen, download functionality with IRM

Answer (score 0):

You can give users 'View Only' permissions on the library.
That should remove the 'Save As' functionality and allow users to just view the documents.

You might need to break permissions on the library if this is to be done seperately.
Or you could simply add the users to a group having 'View Only' permissions. Remove from all other groups.

Comment: Thanks, but this just restricts editing the master document doesn't it? I think 'Save As' and 'Print' will still be available when this is selected.

Comment: I tried this on my server with a user account having only 'View Only' permissions. It works as expected. Please check whether the user for which you are testing has only this permission level.

Answer (score 0):

As Rohit stated: This is event theoretically not possible. Every bit of information a user sees in his browser is already downloaded on his computer.

So you can make it harder to a person to download stuff (block right mouse click, disable buttons etc). But you can't present a file to the user with prevent him to download it.

So the only thing you could do:

- set the file permissions to prevent uploading documents (see post from Abhishek)
- remove the buttons with jQuery (if this is not done automatically)

Removing buttons:
Find out the element id in your browser

```
<input name="SaveButton" id="YOUR_BUTTON_ID".../>
```

Add Some Javascript (e.g. with a content editor webpart (edit page => add webpart => Content Editor)

```
<script>
  $('#YOUR_BUTTON_ID').hide;
</script>
```